How do I make a timer in Assembly 6502?
I'm working on a game and it requires to have a 60 second countdown, but I don't know how to make it count down from 60 seconds since memory is updated so fast.
Here is what i tried:
.proc timer
PHP
PHA
TXA
PHA
TYA
PHA

LDA #60
STA $0000

Loop:
    DEC $0000
    LDA $0000
    BEQ TimerDone
DelayLoop:
    LDX #$FF
InnerLoop:
    DEX
    BNE InnerLoop
    JMP Loop
TimerDone:
    
PLA
TAY
PLA
TAX
PLA
PLP
RTS
.endproc   

What i get is that when i start the game it immediately goes to 0 in the memory viewer, so it updates but its so fast. Is there any way to make some sort of delay that counts in seconds or even milliseconds?

http://www.6502.org/tutorials/interrupts.html might be useful.

Your code is only looping 15300 times (60 * 255), which is probably going to take less than a tenth of a second.  You could increase the size of the loops, and perhaps add a third level of looping, but to get a specific delay, you'd have to know the clock speed of your CPU (and the exact number of clock cycles that each instruction takes) - the CPU has absolutely no knowledge about real-world time intervals.  And this would be the ONLY thing the CPU is doing.  Timing an ongoing operation is vastly easier with hardware support - a timer or clock chip, or periodic interrupts.

Is this on a bare 6502, or are you running on something like the C64?

its in cc65, im using an emulator to run it.

Most NES games counts ticks to measure time which refers to one iteration of the game loop. If your game runs in fixed rate, e.g. 30FPS., you can calculate elapsed time referring to ticks.

You've got is right. You have to use a loop. What you can do to make it take longer is to add NOP operations.
The 6502 has very specific timings. Assuming you do not have a super accelerated modern version of it, you can be extremely precise. The instructions are expected to use exactly the amount of time they are assigned by the reference. So for example the DEX + BNE take 6 cycles while looping, and 5 on the last step (the branch takes 1 less cycle if it is not taken—also it takes 1 more cycles when taken and the destination is on a separate page, the PC high bits are incremented or decremented).
So now you need to find a document with the CPU instructions and the number of cycles each take.
If you have access to a clock, then you could read your clock and use that value to know when you're done. Otherwise, the 6502 has no such thing by default. It has to be some sort of I/O.
                             Cycles
    LDA #60
    STA $0000
Loop:
    DEC $0000                6
    BEQ TimerDone            2 (3 when $0000=0)
DelayLoop:
    LDX #$00                 2
InnerLoop:
    LDY #$00                 2
InnerInnerLoop:
    DEY                      2
    BNE InnerInnerLoop       3 (2 when Y=0)
    DEX                      2
    BNE InnerLoop            3 (2 when X=0)
    JMP Loop                 3
TimerDone:

So, the InnerInnerLoop takes (2 + 3) × 255 + 2 + 2 (last time branch is not taken so 1 less cycle) = 1,284 cycles
As a result the InnerLoop does (2 + 1,284 + 2 + 3) × 255 + (2 + 1,284 + 2 + 2) = 330,495 cycles.
Finally, the Loop does (6 + 2 + 330,495 + 3) × 60¹ + 1 = 19,830,361 cycles.
If you have a 6502 that runs at 1MHz, then that loop would take about 19.8 seconds. If it runs at 5Mhz, then it will take 19.8 ÷ 5 ≈ 3.97 seconds.
¹ As mentioned by Nick Westgate in a comment, as written the loop will perform 59 iterations. You can instead (1) move the DEC where the JMP is and replace the JMP by BNE; or (2) use LDA #61 to get exactly 60 iterations.

Note: a while back, I created an Apple II simulator that runs on x86/amd64 computers. My main problem was the clock. I did not work on that part. So it goes dead fast compared to the good old Apple II. So hopefully you run your code on real hardware. Otherwise, your pause will work only if the emulator properly emulates the duration of a cycle.

Regarding note 1: The code checks $0000 before the "work" (inner loops) are done, so if set to #1, DEC $0000 would be zero and no work would be done. Therefore the current code performs 59 repetitions of the work. Either the DEC $0000 should be moved to after the work, or the branch should be BMI, not BEQ.
